# Centering image with Title Label in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am adding custom title label and custom image to navigation bar. I can correctly add the title label in the position I want but I cannot center **horizontally** the image to that label. I am adding a screenshot and the code I use which can help.

[image]
[image]

```
-(void)addIconInNavBar
{
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(lblHeight, lblHeight);
    CGFloat marginX = (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width) - (imageSize.width / 2);
    CGFloat marginY = (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height / 2) - (imageSize.height / 2);

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(marginX, marginY , imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the better solution is using [custom view](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624935-titleview?language=objc) for the title of the navigation bar.

```
UIView* customViewWithImage = [self createCustomView];
self.navigationItem.titleView = customViewWithImage;
```

You can get attributes of the title from the [title attributes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624953-titletextattributes?language=objc) property, also you can get this information from [appearance](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance).

Answer (score 0):

Please update for centerX as

```
CGFloat marginX = (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width - imageSize.width) / 2;
```

Or

```
CGFloat marginX = (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width/2) - (imageSize.width / 2);
```

Comment: I want to center to the custom title not center to the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this,

Create your custom view and add label and image in your custom view and add this custom view as titleView

```
UIView *vw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lblFrame];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imgFrame];
[vw addSubView:lbl];
[vw addSubView:imgView];
self.navigationItem.titleView = vw;
```